# Solving a Modular arithmetic and exponential equation for an Unknown Variable 's' in Python3 with 4 known and 1 unknown value

Tags: python-3.x

**Question:**

I'm working on a Python3 script where I have the following equation:

```
y = (s * (s**2 - x) * m - 3 * ((s**2 - x) * m) ** 2 * pow(2 * s, -1, p) - (s * x)) % p
```

In this equation, I know the values of *y*, *x*, *m*, and *p*, but I need to solve for the unknown variable *s*. I've simplified the equation as shown above, and I'm looking for a Python3 code or method to find the value of s.Here's what each variable represents:

**y: Known value**

**x: Known value**

**m: Known value**

**p: Known value**

**s: Unknown value**

I'm trying to find the value of s. I've attempted to solve it using the sympy in the below equation

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

s, x, m, p, y = symbols('s x m p y')
equation = Eq((s * (s**2 - x) * m - 3 * ((s**2 - x) * m) ** 2 * pow(2 * s, -1, p) - s * x) % p, y)
solution = solve(equation, s)
print(solution)
```

The output of the above python3 script is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/solve_2.py", line 5, in <module>
    solution = solve(equation, s)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1145, in solve
    solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1693, in _solve
    raise NotImplementedError('\n'.join([msg, not_impl_msg % f]))
NotImplementedError:
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation -y + Mod(-3*m**2*(s**2 - x)**2*Mod(1/(2*s), p) + m*s*(s**2 - x) - s*x, p)
```

but I'm not sure if my approach is correct.
Need guidance on how to solve this equation for s in Python3? If possible, please explain the steps involved so I can understand the solution better.Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you're solving for s why is the equation in the form to compute y from s as a given? Try refactoring to have s = first then attempt to apply sympy. Sympy likely just won't work, (I've encountered issues with solving modular arithmetic w/ it before) but you could manually use numpy.linspaces to create input ranges and np.allclose or something yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `Try refactoring to have s =`

Comment: If you have `y = (s * (s**2 - x) ... % p` Then you need s,m,x,p to calculate y. But you want to use m,x,p,y to calculate s. Keep in mind computer code != math equality. Because mod doesn't have an inverse you can algebraically use, sympy doesn't have any way to refactor and solve. So, you can try to refactor it yourself first to solve for s and hand that to sympy. Either way, to solve for s instead of y you'll have to define some sensible inverse modulus.

Comment: Can you please provide the implementation of the correct script to solve for s using m,p,y and x.